# Apps Script - Remove a Protection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to restrict cell editing in a Google Sheet by only allowing a user to edit empty cells or cells filled by him, but not cells filled by other editors. Put simply :

1. If a cell is blank, any document editor can write content in it
2. Once an editor has put content in a cell, *only him and document owners* should be able to edit it further
3. If a cell is cleared by its author or one of the document's owners, the protection should automatically be removed as well so any editor can now edit it (back to step 1)

I'm trying to use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) to do this, but it looks like that you can't *remove* a [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection), nor get the list of protections that apply to a specific cell.

Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Types of protection**

`Protection` doesn't have to be set on the whole `Sheet`, you can call a `protect()` method on a `Range` of your choosing, be it one cell or a custom `Range`.

**Removing protection**

There is a method dedicated to removing `Protection` from the `Sheet` / `Range`, it is called `remove()`. It can be called on any `Protection` previously acquired via `getProtections()` method call (`getProtections()` method returns an `Array` of all `Protection` instances).

In your case the resulting flow would look like this:

1. The cell is cleared by editor -> call `getProtections()` -> check for target cell -> `remove()`;
2. The cell received a value -> call `protect()` -> add editors via`addEditor()` / `addEditors()`;

Both steps can be put into an installable `onEdit()` trigger, for example to be triggered on cell being edited.

**Sample script**

Once again, what you trying to achieve is possible, try the script below (don't forget to include it as a callback of an installable trigger). It removes other editors from being able to edit this cell until current user empties it and vice versa [UPD: optimized 'getRow()' and 'getColumn()' usage].

```
/**
 * Protects and unprotects ranges;
 * @param {Object} e event object;
 */
function protect(e) {

  //access edited range, value and sheet;
  var rng = e.range;
  var val = e.value;
  var sh  = rng.getSheet();

  //access edited range row and column;
  var row = rng.getRow();
  var col = rng.getColumn();

  //access protections;
  var ps = sh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

  //filter out other cells protections;
  ps = ps.filter(function(p){
   var ptd = p.getRange();
   if(row===ptd.getRow()&&col===ptd.getColumn()) {
     return p;
   }
  })[0];

  //if protection not set -> protect;
  if(!ps) {
    var protection = rng.protect(); //protect Range;
    var users = protection.getEditors(); //get current editors;

    protection.addEditor(Session.getEffectiveUser());
    protection.removeEditors(users); //remove other editors' access;
  }else {
    if(!val) { ps.remove(); } //if cell is empty -> remove protection;
  }

}
```

**Assumptions**

This explanation and sample script assume an environment where `getEffectiveUser()` makes a difference (e.g. script project isn't deployed as a WebApp + `execute as me`, etc.).

**On the importance of `addEditor()`**

As per our discussion in comments, one should beware the possibility of locking themselves out of the editing the cell if not using the `addEditor()` method before `removeEditors()` (testing conditions to replicate are: GSuite Spreadsheet owner, Gmail editor user, permissions set to "Off", installable `onEdit()` trigger). Take a look at what might happen:

[image]

**Useful links**

1. `addEditor()` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#addeditoremailaddress);
2. `remove()` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#remove());
3. `getProtections()` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getProtections(ProtectionType));

Comment: I completely missed `getProtections()`, now it works! However `addEditor()` isn't needed since you'll always be in the list of editors for the protections you create (and owners too).

Comment: Glad it works! The thing is, this `addEditor()` is actually necessary here - try removing the `addEditor()` method  call - you should be locked out of the cell edit (I tested it on account with edit permissions but not the owner)

Comment: Well I did the exact same test with a second account (non-owner editor) and I still had edit rights on the cell after the protection was added... weird

Comment: How curious - my exact testing conditions were: Gsuite account owner + consumer (gmail) account user, permission rights "off", consumer account set to "can edit" -> without this statement consumer account locks itself out of editing - what's your configuration? I would suggest leaving it just in case (will make a small screencast shortly to illustrate)

Comment: Ok I see, it's because you're removing the editors you get from `proctection.getEditors()`, while I'm using `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getEditors()` :). Also, I don't know if it makes a difference but in my case all accounts are simple Google / Gmail accounts, no G Suite accounts involved.

Comment: I see (btw, this is the idea - remocing editors from protection while leaving them be shert editors :) Not sure if it changes anything, since consumer account's permision doesn't come from any group (though, I'll double-check later today)

Answer (score 0):

Using real protection-no.

What you could do.

create an OnEdit function that records the value and the user for the cell in metadata or a note. (a note would be less secure but easier to debug).

On each edit of the cell it checks for this metadata, and if the user is not the same/admin, it reverts the content of the text to value that was saved for the cell before (probably with a popup saying "that is not your cell to edit").

Add something to the bottom of the function that says that if the edit is to no value, to clear the metadata.