How to set protections on sheet sections both on startup and on cell after user edit
So I am trying to set up a google sheet that dozens of users are going to use and I want to automate the protection schemes since a new sheet is being made everyday. I'm trying to have sheet headers and certain columns protected from all users (besides explicit exceptions) and when an edit is made to a cell, edit permissions for all users are removed. I've tried attempting removing permissions both using the onOpen and onEdit functions via setUnprotectedRanges() and the regular range.protect() like in the documentation. But every time I try the onOpen, it breaks the other. I don't know how to keep setting these because permissions need to be removed for as many users possible (besides editor and owner). Here's what I have for the cell protection removal after edit that does work:
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = e.range;
  if (editedCell.getColumn() == 4 && editedCell.getRow() > 1) {
    var link = editedCell.getValue();
    
    // If a link is pasted (non-empty cell)
    if (link != "") {
      var row = editedCell.getRow();
      var currentTime = new Date(); // Get current date and time
      
      // Set the timestamp in column F
      sheet.getRange(row, 6).setValue(currentTime);
      
      // Set the formula in column G to calculate elapsed time
      var elapsedTimeFormula = '=IF(F' + row + '<>"", NOW() - F' + row + ', "")';
      sheet.getRange(row, 7).setFormula(elapsedTimeFormula);

      // Protect the specific cell in column D where the link was pasted
      var cellToProtect = sheet.getRange(row, 4);
      var protection = cellToProtect.protect().setDescription('Cell Locked After Link Added');
      //var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
      //if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
      //}
    }
  }
}

As for protecting certain columns and rows onOpen(), version history failed me there but it was along the lines of:
function onOpen(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Default Protected Headers and Columns');
  var unprotectedLeftOfColumns = sheet.getRange('A2:H1000');
  var unprotectedRightOfColumns = sheet.getRange('J2:N1000');
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges([unprotected]);

  // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
  // permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.
  //var me = Session.getEffectiveUser(); [Doesn't work for some reason for two users on same computer]
  //protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  //if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  //}


Using these methods I keep getting errors but I can't find the documentation for them so its really hard trying to debug this. At this point it's easier to but the header and column protections when copying the sheet, but I'm not the one doing it so I can't be sure it's done. The protection app script documentation is starting to look bleak, I wouldn't even be sure about the other methods like removeEditor() since it's a large sheet shared by link and speed is key. Any help would be highly appreciated because I can't find much about any of these issues.
Update:
The current error I'm getting:
Google Apps Script: Exception: Domain edit permissions may not be set on spreadsheets that are not on a domain.

1) protection.setUnprotectedRanges([unprotected]); "unprotected" is not defined. Are you trying to unprotect two ranges - "unprotectedLeftOfColumns" and "unprotectedRightOfColumns"? 2) Using these methods I keep getting errors Please provide details of the errors.

Doesn't work for some reason for two users on same computer Is this intended as a sarcastic comment? If not, please explain the process whereby multiple users login and open a spreadsheet on the same computer.

since a new sheet is being made everyday Please explain the process for making a new sheet (a spreadsheet file?, or a new sheet within a single file?) every day. FWIW, I'm not surprised about the problems caused by onOpen because this is executed when any user opens the spreadsheet. So it would "undo" any previous onEdit changes. I think I would apply the onOpen changes at the same time as I make the new "sheet" - this would set up the unprotected ranges before any user has access to the sheet.

Regarding creating multiple unprotected ranges, refer protection.setUnprotectedRanges - Google Apps Script. I've tested this and it works just like it says on the tin.

to add with @Tedinoz questions and suggestions, for starters, if you are going to use the setUnprotectedRanges onOpen method, that would mean that it will over write current protections that was set by the OnEdit, you can treat protections as a giant list of ranges that have some protection rules and re initiating it makes no sense it is like you are trying to create a list but clears it every time you open the paper.

Also if you are using removeEditors(), using an OnEdit, it will result in some issue because Neither the owner of the spreadsheet nor the current user can be removed. based on the https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#removeeditorsemailaddresses

@Tedinoz Thanks for the reponses. as for your many comments:

Yes the left and right of column ranges were suppose to be in the setUnprotectedRanges argument as [leftOfColumn, rightOfColumn]. I'll update to to show more of the errors
Two users on the same computer, for google sheets, the collaborative platform, there's incognito tabs. You can figure that out. You're a smart cookie
Right click sheet -> Duplicate. I'm trying conditionals that check the protection description to prevent multiple users trying to set protections. But even then I haven't seen those protections duplicated


@Tedinoz 4) The protections work on the tin, but break the other protection script that adds a new protection rule for each time a cell in a specific column is edited

@Alma_Matters 1)That's close to the behavior I'm seeing. Protections set by a previous user from the onEdit function still exist after another user opens the sheet, but the ability to write more by any other user than the one who last opened the sheet are do not work. Even the script to add time stamps fails. I've thought about moving it to the onEdit function and checking if the protection exists before adding it again. But I'm still trying to get them to work together and trying different arguments to set protections aside from unprotectedRanges. 2)Yeah, I know, I did say that in the post

This question looks to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56692164/1595451

Avoiding Conflicts from Duplicate Protections:
You can start with this code, as you are aware of the current limitations I have mentioned in the comments. I do think what you are just missing is correctly creating conditions where it is good to create protection. Which what I have added on this code, it first checks if current protection is existent if yes, then a duplicate protection should not be added to avoid conflicts between protections.
Sample Code:
function onOpen() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  console.log(protections.length)
  if (protections.length < 1) {
    var headerRange = ss.getRange("A1:J1");// This is where the initialization happens of with your template data. Getting the range of the Template Headers and columns
    var protectedCols = ss.getRange("A2:C19"); // Additional holder in case the range you are looking forward to protect is cannot be contained by 1 variable.

    var protections1 = headerRange.protect().setDescription("Test Protection");
    var protections2 = protectedCols.protect().setDescription("Test Protection");
    protections1.addEditor("Change to your Preferred Email");
    protections1.removeEditors(protections1.getEditors());
    protections2.addEditor("Change to your Preferred Email");
    protections2.removeEditors(protections2.getEditors());
    SpreadsheetApp.flush() // Just making sure that the changes will be applied
  }
}


function onEdit(e) {
  var editedCell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var editedCol = e.range.getColumn();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var protectionsList = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  var protectionListRange = protectionsList.map(x => x.getRange().getA1Notation()); // getting ranges that already have protection this way you will not end up with infinite numbers of protection.
  if (editedCol == 4) {
    var ranges = ss.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 4, 1, 3);
    if (!protectionListRange.includes(ranges.getA1Notation())) {
      var currentProtection = ranges.protect().setDescription("Edited Protection");
      currentProtection.addEditor("Change to your Preferred Email");
      currentProtection.removeEditors(currentProtection.getEditors());

    }
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}

To create protection, it limits the ability to edit the template columns and headers based on the email that you will explicitly declare on the code, along with the first one who opens the spreadsheet. This way it will only run during the initialization. The onEdit creates protection that is limiting the edit ability of everyone aside from the explicitly declared email and who made the edit that runs the protection.
Sample Output:

Reference:
Class Protection

There is no need to include SpreadsheetApp.flush() when there is no other command after it.
